# Scope of exception object in C++

Tags: c++, exception, scope

What is the scope of the exception object in C++? does it go out of scope as soon as catch handler is executed? Also, if I create an unnamed exception object and throw it, then while catching that exception does it matter if I catch it by const reference or a non-const reference?

Comment: Are you asking about the *lifetime*?

Comment: Yes..when is it going to be destructed?

Comment: To clarify Joren's question: the term _scope_ usually refers to the region (lines of code) where the variable has a name. The word _scope_ is often misused to mean _lifetime_, which is, as you understood, how long the variable actually resides in memory.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this is also consistent with the standard (n4296) 3.8 "lifetime of an object is a runtime property", 3.3 "each particular name is valid only within some possibly discontiguous
portion of program text called its scope" - thus, scope refers to source code. I had never thought about this distinction.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When a `throw` expression is evaluated, an exception object is initialized from the value of the expression. The exception object which is thrown gets its type from the static type of the throw expression ignoring any `const` and `volatile` qualifiers. For class types this means that *copy-initialization* is performed.

The exception object's scope is outside of the scope of the block where the throw occurs. Think of it as living in a special exception area off to one side of the normal call stack where local objects live.

Inside a `catch` block, the name initialized with the caught exception object is initialized with this exception object and not the argument to `throw`, even if this was an lvalue.

If you `catch` via non-const reference, then you can mutate the exception object, but not what it was initialized from. You can alter the behaviour of the program if you re-throw the exception in ways that you couldn't if you caught by value or const reference (`const_cast`s aside).

The exception object is destroyed when the last catch block that does not exit via a re-throw (i.e. a parameterless throw expression evaluation) completes.

Comment: What is _the last catch block_? `catch(...) { std::exception *p = nullptr; try { throw; } catch (const std::exception &e) { p = &e; } catch(...) {} if (p) { std::cerr << p->what() << std::endl; } }` Is this valid code? The inner catch doesn't exits via a re-throw. Is the outer _catch(...)_ the last block?

Answer (score 9):

The exception object is available only in `catch` block. You cannot use the exception object outside the `catch` block. Following steps happen when you throw an exception and catch:

```
try
{
 MyException anObject;
 throw anObject;  //1

}
catch(MyException exObject)
{
}
```

- The `throw` clause (//1) receives the local object `anObject`, and treats it as a value argument: it creates a copy of the `anObject`.
- the `catch` handler catches an MyException  Object,which again is a value parameter. At this moment another copy is created.
- If the `catch` handler would have implemented so as to receive a reference to an object `(catch (MyException &o))`, the second copy is avoided.
- if `catch` handler receives the exception object by `const&` then you can only call `const` methods.

Comment: Creating objects outside the `throw` statement is a pretty bad idea, precisely because that could lead to a redundant copy. Do `throw Myexception();` instead. Apart from that, if you declare an exception object with a name (as in this answer) then *of course* it can be accessed outside the `catch` block in the scope it was declared in — in this case, inside the `try` block.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the object you throw goes out of scope almost immediately. What's going to be caught by exception handlers is a *copy* of original object. That copy will be deleted after catch handler is executed *unless* you catch it by value (not by reference). In this case there will be another copy created. But you should catch it by reference (preferably const one) anyway.

Comment: What about throwing a pointer to something as per MFC? You need to consider objects other than objects of class type as implied in the question and your answer.

Comment: Pointers get copied too but nobody cares usually :)