# where C++ exception parameter store in memory?

Tags: c++

I have doubt in C++ exception :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void some_function()
{
    string str("Hello,World!");
    throw(str);
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        some_function();
    }
    catch (string& e)
    {
        cout << e << endl;
        e = "Hello, the world!";
        cout << e << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

debug in my PC:

1. in `some_function` the `str` addr: `0x003CF820`
2. int `main` the `e` addr: `0x003CF738`

I have three question,

1. catch parameter is `string&`, why we get diff addr in main() ?
2. is `str` not a temp value ? why we can use a temp value reference ?
3. where is `e` store in memory ?

can some one help me ? thanks .

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654150/scope-of-exception-object-in-c

Comment: That question is not a duplicate but the [top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1654187/15416) there also covers this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Objects that are thrown are typically copied/moved to, or directly constructed in, a memory area reserved for them - distinct from the normal function call stack and "heap".  So, the address of the local `str` object in `some_function()` can't be expected to match the address of the string instance caught in `main()`.  This model allows the lifetimes of the thrown objects to be decoupled from the stack unwinding that happens until they're caught.  (It also means that it ***may*** be possible - you'd want to check your implementation documentation if you cared - to throw an exception even when the remaining stack and/or heap is insufficient to store the value thrown, though many exception objects use further dynamically storage - for example, for `std::string` objects with text longer than any internal short-string-optimisation buffer).

See 15.1/4:

> The memory for the exception object is **allocated in an unspecified way**, except as noted in 3.7.4.1.

In 3.7.4.1:

> [ Note: In particular, **a global allocation function is not called to allocate storage for** objects with static
>   storage duration (3.7.1), for objects or references with thread storage duration (3.7.2), for objects of type
>   std::type_info (5.2.8), or for **an exception object** (15.1). —end note ]